# CSS transparent border showing border in Windows FF

Tags: css, firefox

Im creating a CSS triangle, code:

```
display: block;
width: 0px;
height: 0px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px 0px 9px 9px;
border-color: transparent transparent rgb(255, 255, 255);
position: absolute;
top: 14px;
left: 133px;
```

The problem is that this triangle is rendering a border in Firefox 16.0.2 while using windows 7.

Screen Shot of triangle in FF - There are two triangles, superior and inferior, creating the same shadow
[image: Screen Shot of triangle in FF - There are two triangles, superior and inferior, creating the same shadow]

I checked in MAC's FF and it does not show any border for the triangle.

The triangle displays correctly in Chrome, Safari, IE, Opera, MAC and Windows

Any idea why this is happening??

EDIT:

you can check it here: https://metrikstudios.com/want/fbapp/triangle-display.php The page displays the code shown above with a larger triangle

Comment: Where is the triangle - http://jsfiddle.net/HvMAt/

Comment: there are two triangles in the image. Bottom right and top right. Both are white, but they are rendering a border at their left face

Comment: Where is the image mate?

Comment: Probally ur image link is broken - http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn6zw.png

Comment: @BoltClock: Strange. No image is shown in IE9 on Windows 7. Must be my damned ISP again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using rgba colours instead, like so:

border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) rgb(255, 255, 255);

The default border colour is black, so maybe these borders are a weird transition artifact.
Instead of moving from invisible black to solid white, you'd be moving from invisible white to solid white.

Comment: i need the transparent border, since Im creating a triangle

Comment: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) is transparent, it's full-white at 0% opacity. Trust me, it'll do what you need, I ran browsershots and everything.

Comment: hey, misread your post. I thought you ment repleacing transparent with other rgb color. Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the fine line between the two triangles in my example?

```
.one {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 90px 90px;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
}
.two {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 90px 90px;
    border-color: transparent rgb(0, 0, 0) transparent;
    position: absolute;
}


<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

I see this line on every Browser on Win7 i have tested. I think it is rendered this way and you won't get rid of this. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4H9Pu/1/)

Comment: nope, its a line of the triangle. In my case i just joined wo triangles, but the line is shown even if I use only one of them. THe line is only rendered in Window's FF, not in any other browser/os. You can try my code to see it yourself

Comment: I've tried your code and there was no line in FF Win7. That's why I thought you mean something like in my example.

Comment: you can check it here: https://metrikstudios.com/want/fbapp/triangle-display.php. There is a triangle with a line. I just checked in FF 16.0.2 Win7 and i see the line

Comment: Same OS and same FF on two devices but still no line.